# How to test if modifier with keycode is down

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class KeyListener implements KeyEventDispatcher
{
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
        {
            if(e.isDown(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()) && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_V)
            {
                paste();
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `e.isDown` doesn't exist.
What alterntives can use so that it is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for macs and <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for other OS'es?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyEvent extends InputEvent so you can use the `isControlDown()` method of InputEvent.

Edit: I found this link which shows how to create a KeyStroke for the command key:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2007/May/msg00243.html

So instead of using a KeyEventDispatcher, you should be using [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). Key Bindings allow you to invoke an Action for a given KeyStroke. Swing was designed to use Key Bindings.

Comment: +1 for [`getMenuShortcutKeyMask()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getMenuShortcutKeyMask%28%29), which returns `InputEvent.META_MASK` on Mac OS X, corresponding to the ⌘ key.